# yasm writing to PAGEZERO in x86_64 mach-o format

Tags: macos, linker, ld, mach-o, yasm

I'm following a assembly book which uses the yasm assembler and ld linker.  I'm on OSX 10.12 and I'm trying to assembly to Mach-O format.  Unfortunately, I'm receiving a segmentation fault.  This is the original .asm file:

```
BITS 64
segment .data
a dd 4

segment .bss
g resd 1

segment .text
global start
start:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 16

    xor eax, eax
    leave
    ret
```

I compile it:

> yasm -f macho64 -m amd64 -l memory.lst -o memory.o memory.asm

link it:

> ld memory.o -o memory

and run it in lldb, I receive this error:

> - thread #1: tid = 0xb3b4b, 0x0000000000000001, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)
>     frame #0: 0x0000000000000001
>     error: error reading data from section __PAGEZERO

In lldb, I ran 'target modules dump sections', and I see that it's __PAGEZERO segment is defined as so:

> [0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000001000)  ---  memory.__PAGEZERO

I looked at a normal Mach-O binary built with clang, and the __PAGEZERO segment looks like this:

> [0x0000000000000000-0x0000000100000000)  --- test.__PAGEZERO

I then noticed that it's actually the linker that creates the PAGEZERO segment.  I believe clang uses a special linker called 'lld'.  My question is:

1. Is my error actually caused by reading from PAGEZERO.
2. If so, can I tell my linker (ld) to define PAGEZERO in the correct size?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: I changed the link command to:

> ld memory.o -macosx_version_min 10.12 -lSystem -o memory

This doesn't change the PAGEZERO size, so I'm not sure how it fixed it, but it works now.

Comment: You could inspect both output binaries with MachoView to see what's exactly going on inside.